# Adjust font size relative to another font size in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, font-size

Is it possible in InDesign to globally adjust the size of font *A* relative to the size of another font *B* so that given the same "Font Size" they have always the same height of their lowercase letters?

I know that in CSS there is a property [`font-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) that makes this possible, but is there anything like that in InDesign?

It could look like specifing a multiplier for a font that is automatically allowed for when changing "Font Size".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a character style and set the scale appropriately.

Place guides at the baseline and x-height of the base font to help you do the alignment. Then in the character style of the second font, under *Advanced Character Formats*, set an equal horizontal and vertical scale so that the x-heights align. For example:

"Porttitor" is set in a different typeface with a larger x-height:

[image]

With the character style applied, the x-heights align, regardless of the font size:

[image]